# Rails has_one association when there are multiple records with foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I understand `has_one` correctly, the foreign key is on the associated record. This means that I could have multiple related records on the "foreign" side. When I use the `has_one` records to get the associated record, how do I determine which one will be returned?

Here's an example:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :activity_state
end

class ActivityState < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
end
```

Let's say there are 2 rows in the `activity_states` table that have their foreign key set to Job #1

```
ActivityState.where(job_id: 1).select(:id, :job_id)
#=> [#<ActivityState id: 1, job_id: 1>, #<ActivityState id: 2, job_id: 1]
```

When I try to get the `activity_state` from the JobRequest, how do I determine which one is returned?

```
JobRequest.find(1).activity_state
#=> #<ActivityState id: 1, job_id: 1>
```

Right now, it looks like it is returning the first one it finds.

What if I wanted to return the *latest* one that was created?

Comment: Wasn't sure how to phrase this question, feel free to update the title

Comment: If you have more than one `ActivityState` associated with Job, then your association on job should be `has_many :activity_states`

Comment: @Vimsha That's a good related question, I guess. The DB schema will look the same regardless of it's `has_one` or `has_many`, right? So, should I be creating an AR validation to make sure there aren't multiple `activity_states` for each Job?

Comment: @mehulkar Correct, the DB structure will look the same. To answer the second question, its hard to give a definite "yes" or "no" as it would depend on how your system is setup. How are `ActivityState` records created; is there any way they can be created more than once for the same `Job`? If so, then I would say either alter your system to that the system **cannot** create more than one per job, or implement Vimsha's idea and use an `order("created_at DESC")` method to grab the last one.

Comment: Thanks @PaulRichter. It seems like `has_one` is easy to mess up, then. If it isn't complemented by some sort of validation, it could lead to a lot of confusing situations.

Comment: Made a PR to guides to mention this. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18216

Comment: @mehulkar I should correct my earlier post actually. If you were to do something like `@job.activity_state = @new_activity_state`, the old associated object has its `job_id` reset to null, so in that way Rails attempts to enforce your `has_one` relationship. However, if you were associating them some other way, such as something like `@activity_state.job = @job` or anything along those lines, you might have been circumventing that enforcement.

Comment: @PaulRichter ahh interesting. That helps. I was doing `ActivityState.create(job_id: @job.id)`. Assigning seems better.

Comment: @mehulkar Yeah, that's exactly the circumvention I mentioned. So in that case, hypothetically you could simply change it  `@job.activity_state = ActivityState.new(...activity state params...)`, and that would solve the issue of multiple states per job. If you want to keep a history of some kind though, then Humza's or Vimsha's `has_many` is the way to go. I probably should have made this in to an answer, in retrospect. If its helpful, let me know and I will do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the main issue is that your system is creating multiple `ActivityState` objects for each job. As you mentioned, your original code was doing this:

```
ActivityState.create(job_id: @job.id)
```

The problem is that the old `ActivityState` still contains the `job_id` for that job. Consequently, when you executed `@job.activity_state`, you were indeed seeing the first (and old) activity state because it is the first in the database. Specifically, the `has_one` relationship executes a `LIMIT 1` sql clause, so technically the "first" record is dependent on however your database was ordering the records (usually by order of entry)

Normally, for a `has_one` relationship, if you were to do

```
@job.activity_state = ActivityState.new(...activity state params...)
```

Rails attempts to enforce the "one association per record" concept by resetting the "old" associated record's `job_id` column to null. Your original code was unintentionally circumventing that enforcement. If you change it to this line of code instead, you will allow Rails to work its magic and ensure consistent behaviour with your association.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a has_many association in this case. To return a particular record based on a column, create a method.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :activity_states

  def latest_activity_state
    self.activity_states.order("updated_at ASC").last # or created_at, depends
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think @PaulRichter's answer is the more correct solution in my case though.